# Vue.JS : TS2339: Property '...' does not exist on type '{ components: {

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I'm using Vue with single files components (in reality I'm trying to split those .vue components into 3 different files, the .vue having script and style tags that each calls a separated file)

But in this file :

```
import modelsList from '@/components/modelsList/modelsList.vue';
import bookerService from '@/services/booker.ts';

export default {
    components: { modelsList },
    data: function() {
        return {
            homeModels: [] as any[],
        };
    },
    created: function() {
        this.homeModels = bookerService.getHomeModels();
    },
};
```

I've got the error message :

> TS2339: Property 'homeModels' does not exist on type '{ components: {
> modelsList: VueConstructor; }; data: () => { homeModels: any[];
> }; created: () => void; }'.

Do you know what happens here ?

And, little bonus question, do you know why if I don't add the file extension in the imports, I get an error like :

> Cannot find module '@/components/modelsList/modelsList' or its corresponding type declarations.

---

Here is my tsconfig.json :

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "esnext",
        "strict": true,
        "module": "esnext",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "removeComments": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "paths": {
            "@/*": [
                "assets/vue/*"
            ]
        },
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "jsx": "preserve",
        "importHelpers": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "types": [
            "webpack-env"
        ],
        "lib": [
            "esnext",
            "dom",
            "dom.iterable",
            "scripthost"
        ]
    },
    "include": [
        "src/**/*.ts",
        "src/**/*.tsx",
        "src/**/*.vue",
        "tests/**/*.ts",
        "tests/**/*.tsx"
    ],
    "files": [
        "assets/vue/vue-shims.d.ts"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

Comment: which version of vue are you using?

Answer (score 0):

OK just found out that there was an error in the "include" array of the tsconfig.json :

Had to replace the "src/" parent folder of each include to the real folder of my vue project, relatively to the tsconfig.json, that is "assets/vue/" for me.